# sort rows based on fields from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

I have two tables as follows:

**Table 1 (t1)**

```
______________________________________________________________________________________________
RequestId | Raised_By | CommentDate | Comment | AttachmentName | Attachment | AttachmentSize |
----------+-----------+-------------+---------+----------------+------------+----------------+
```

**Table 2 (t2)**

```
______________________________________________
RequestId | CommentDate | Comment | Raised_By |
----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

Note: `CommentDate` is a `timestamp`

I want to select the only one record i.e comment from table `t1` or `t2`, whose `RequestId=RequestId` and the `CommentDate` is the latest.

My query is as follows:

```
(SELECT Comment from t1 WHERE RequestId = "."\"".$_POST['RequestId']."\" and Raised_By="."\"".$_POST['Raised_By']."\" and CommentDate="."\"".$_POST['CommentDate']."\")
UNION 
(SELECT Comment from t2 WHERE RequestId = "."\"".$_POST['RequestId']."\" and Raised_By="."\"".$_POST['Raised_By']."\" )
ORDER BY CommentDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But I am getting an error saying `unknown column CommentDate`.

Comment: Hmmmm, so perhaps you need to qualify the column name. Can you show your table's layout information?

Comment: t1-RequestId, Raised_By,CommentDate,Comment,AttachmentName,Attachment,AttachmentSize    t2-RequestId, CommentDate,Comment,RaisedBy

Answer (score 1):

Can you `ORDER BY` if you have not SELECTED that ?
We need to understand the sequence in which query executes. Unless you select the field `'CommentDate'` you cannot arrange in order.

Try to select the `'CommentDate'` along with `'Comment'` and check

```
(SELECT Comment, CommentDate from t1 WHERE RequestId = "."\"".$_POST['RequestId']."\" and Raised_By="."\"".$_POST['Raised_By']."\" and CommentDate="."\"".$_POST['CommentDate']."\")
UNION 
(SELECT Comment, CommentDate from t2 WHERE RequestId = "."\"".$_POST['RequestId']."\" and Raised_By="."\"".$_POST['Raised_By']."\" )
ORDER BY CommentDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use `UNION` when you can `JOIN` both tables?

```
SELECT t1.Comment,
    CASE WHEN t1.CommetDate > t2.CommentDate
    THEN t1.commentDate
    ELSE t2.commentDate
    END AS commentDate
  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.RequestId = t2.RequestId
  ORDER BY commentDate DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Only use `INNER JOIN` if there's always a record that matches the specified `RequestID` in both tables. Also, you must return the proper comment for the latest comment date, not always return t1.Comment.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I interpreted the OP that there are always items in both tables (since s/he said "whose RequestID=RequestID"). As for the proper comment, do I need another `CASE` or is there a better way to do it?